# How to get all images URLs from Firebase for a particular user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am adding images for all user in storage section, below is my code for uploading images.

```
public void uploadImage(byte[] data, final String fileName) {
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading image....");
    mProgressDialog.show();

    StorageReference filepath=mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(fileName);
    filepath.putBytes(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            String mUrl=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();

            // got url for this image what to do with this url.....
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this,"Upload done!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

I want to obtain all images url stored for a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for listing items of Firebase Storage on the client side.

You should modify your file upload method to also store that download URL somewhere in the user's control, like a user-specific path in the Realtime Database.

Comment: I can store the URLs in the Realtime Database,     Suppose I have a class for Users Image  -->       class UserImages{ map<String,String> imageMap=new HashMap<>(); public void addImageUrl(String img,String Url){ map.put(img,Url);}  } , I can store that object for a particular user in Realtime Database ,But the main problem I am facing is How to retrieve this  object of a particular user from realtime database.