# Firebase storage and database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase database that I access from my Angular2 app:

```js
Lafayette_apartments
description:
  "description"
link:
  "/lafayette-apts"
title:
  "Lafayette Apartments"
url:
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gadaphotos/photos/port..."
Scotchbrook_apartments
description:
  "This is a real estate photography taken for Sco..."
link:
  "/scotchbrook"
title:
  "Scotchbrook Apartments"
url:
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gadaphotos/photos/port..."
alden_park
new_port_village
description:
  "description"
link:
  "/new-port-village"
title:
  "New Port Village"
url:
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gadaphotos/photos/port..."
```

I also have several folders with photos in the same Firebase storage.

```
Name    Size    Type    Last modified
 alden_park/
—
lafayette_apts/
—
Scotchbrook_apartments/
```

How can I list the name of each folder, and the photo URL inside the folders in my database to each respective content?

Comment: There is no client-side JavaScript API to list files or folders from Firebase Storage. You can use the gcloud server-side APIs or will have to keep a list of the files somewhere, e.g. by keeping the URLs in the database as you already do with the S3 URLs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38041775, http://stackoverflow.com/q/38762731, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40567716, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40446423 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/37335102.